# How can I overlay regions on to a map?

Tags: ios, objective-c, maps, overlay

I know that objective-c has overlay API's but I am kind of new to map drawing and was curious as to how it works.  Is there a way to pre-draw the regions onto a map and then read from this map? Do I have to get every single little point in a region and read that? How does it all work?

Let's say I want to have a border for every city in the state of New York, how can this be achieved?

Or let's say I want to draw a border for the neighborhood I live in.  Sky's the limit but I am unsure how to do this.  Even if I have to hire someone to draw regions, how does it all work?

I've done some research on the API's but not sure how to have the drawings.

In this example `http://www.shawngrimes.me/2011/04/adding-polygon-map-overlays/` I see that for a polygon, there are a lot of points that were used to draw that as I assume each time you change direction even the slightest bit, you need a new point as it's not like a straight line that goes from one point to another.

What I am looking for is to have someone pre-draw the regions that I need (probably pay someone) and be able to read from a region.  How does this work, would someone have to give me every single point? Or do I get some some image of a map with the overlays drawn?

Answer (score 0):

There are a few different MKOverlay types for doing this such as MKCirce and MKPolygon the add an overlay it is a two step process. First of all you would add the MKOverlay to the application secondly you need to override the

```
- (MKOverlayView *)mapView:(MKMapView *)map viewForOverlay:(id <MKOverlay>)overlay
```

The first stage defines the overlay the function would be used to create the view that would represent that overlay.

The code below is taken from an application I developed that puts circle overlays on to a map to indicate a search area.

The following code is set any point after the map is initialised

```
circle = [MKCircle circleWithCenterCoordinate:target.center radius:target.radius];
[map addOverlay:circle];
```

This section of code is used to create the actual view

```
- (MKOverlayView *)mapView:(MKMapView *)map viewForOverlay:(id <MKOverlay>)overlay
{
  MKCircleView *circleView = [[MKCircleView alloc] initWithOverlay:overlay];
  circleView.strokeColor = [UIColor systemGreen];
  circleView.fillColor = [[UIColor systemGreen] colorWithAlphaComponent:0.2];
  return circleView;
}
```

This creates a green circle based on the position and radius of a CLRegion object.

*Note if you are going to use multiple types of MKOverlays you would want to do a type test in the viewForOverlay function.

Hope this helps.